# Error while sign in to google play games services : looper.prepare() can't be called

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am getting this error from my play developer console:-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:793)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.showFailureDialog(GameHelper.java:953)
    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.showFailureDialog(GameHelper.java:920)
    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.giveUp(GameHelper.java:898)
    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.resolveConnectionResult(GameHelper.java:865)
    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(GameHelper.java:662)
    at com.sdsmdg.cycle.AndroidLauncher.signIn(AndroidLauncher.java:90)
    at com.sdsmdg.cycle.screens.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:41)
    at com.sdsmdg.cycle.CGame.create(CGame.java:23)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1381)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1138)
```

It looks like it crashes when the user is unable to sign in to google play services, but I am unable to figure out the solution to this problem.

Here is the source code for the game:-
https://github.com/harshit211997/Hitball

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
     }
 });`

instead of just

`gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();`

?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display the AlertDialog from Background Thread .To show your Dialog add Looper.prepare() or display the dialog with mainUiThread.

Comment: I know that bit, but how to do that exactly. I am calling gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(); from my mainActivity and rest is taken care by the play games library